# Why do I get the error "Can not read property undefined"?

Tags: javascript, properties, undefined

I am having trouble displaying X in this code below. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var myObj, x = "";

myObJ = {
  "dialogsom": [{
      "id": "1",
      "narration": "Hello there"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "narration": "Hello There 2"
    }
  ]
}

x += myObj.dialogsom[0].narration;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

All I get in this is a can not read property dialogsom undefined error. Any thoughts?

Comment: `myObJ` is defined; `myObj` is `undefined`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: `myObJ` is not the same as `myObj` (first one ends with an uppercase `j`).

Comment: There is no JSON anywhere in your question. JavaScript is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .You have used wrong variable "myObj" You have to use 'myObJ'